# Fetching data using PDO

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

I have `<table>` that display data. I have a button if I click, the data will be displayed in `#datacontainer`. But the problem is "error: expects parameter 1" I don't know what that's mean. Please help me out of this problem

Here's my code

HTML - here's the table, imagine that I have 4 data in my table then when I clicked the button, the `#datacontainer` will show with the data.

```
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th width="15%;">Image</th>
    <th width="0">ID</th>
    <th width="50%;">Name</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>

 <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($accounts)) { ?>

    <tr>
    <td><img src="images/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" id="text_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?>, <?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <i class="fab fa-reddit-alien" id="showdatacontainer" onclick="return chk()"></i>
        <i class="far fa-edit"  style="margin: 0 7% 0 7%;"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
    </td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
<div id="datacontainer"></div>
```

and here's my script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function chk()
{

var id = document.getElementById('text_id').value;
var dataString = ':id='+ id;
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "showdata.php",
  data:dataString,
  cache:false,
  success: function(data){
    $("#datacontainer").html(data);
    $("#datacontainer").slideToggle(300);
  }
});
return false;
```

}

and here's my PHP that what I'm saying when I clicked the button. The error shows that `"Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result"` please help me out of this problem. I really don't know what that's problem. Thankyou

```
    <?php 
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'psbr');

 if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

    $id = $_POST['id']; 
    $accountsdata = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM accounts where id=:id");
    $statement = $db->prepare($accountsdata);
    $statement->bindParam(":id", $id);
    $statement->execute();
    $data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ARRAY);
    }
 ?>

 <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="w"><h1>Name</h1></td>
    </tr>
     <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $val['lastname']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing PDO and MySQLi. Use only one, not both

Comment: what should I do? @Phil

Comment: **Use only one, not both**

Comment: Also, `':id='+ id` isn't a valid `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string. Try just using an object, eg `data: {id: id}`

Comment: Also, you don't want to use `mysqli_query` since your SQL has paramters. On that note though, MySQLi does not support named parameters, only positional. There's really a lot of problems in your code so I suggest you start with some simple tutorials. Try this one ~ https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing `mysqli` and `pdo` see here:

```
</tr>
     <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { ?>
<tr>
```

you need to  change:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="w"><h1>Name</h1></td>
    </tr>
     <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $val['lastname']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
 </table>
```

With:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="w"><h1>Name</h1></td>
    </tr>
     <?php foreach ($data as $val) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $val['lastname']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
 </table>
```

And you are passing wrong `dataString` in your ajax code.

Change:

```
var id = document.getElementById('text_id').value;
var dataString = ':id='+ id;
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "showdata.php",
  data:dataString,
  cache:false,
  success: function(data){
    $("#datacontainer").html(data);
    $("#datacontainer").slideToggle(300);
```

With

```
var id = document.getElementById('text_id').value;
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "showdata.php",
    data:{'id':id},
    cache:false,
    success: function(data){
    $("#datacontainer").html(data);
    $("#datacontainer").slideToggle(300);
```